# Temporary table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a temporary table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-oracle)

I have a SQL query that produces a table that I would like to reuse several times.  In T-SQL I would create a temporary table (#temp), what is the equivalent in Oracle SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: What does google have to say?

Comment: Google talks about global temporary tables, but in SQL no specific permission is needed to create #temp tables.  When I try to create a global temp table in oracle it says I don't have permission.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a way to create temp tables without specific permissions. Ask your DBA to grant the CREATE TABLE permission to you. If you need temporary storage in PL/SQL, consider using a [PL/SQL collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm) type.

Comment: @N. West, that's bad advice and not the way temporary tables work in oracle

Comment: In general you don't need temp tables as much in Oracle as in SQL Server (because of it's more efficient locking implementation). In most of the cases I have seen you can simply replace the SQL Server temp table with the corresponding select (or use a WITH clause)

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tables work differently in oracle than in sql server. I would recommend to read the corresponding chapter in the oracle documentation. To reuse the the contents of the table use the "preserve rows" clause on commit.