# how to combine these two queries

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all

I am using the same table and columns for both queries, but I have different aliases and avg function. How would I be able to combine these two queries with UNION ALL because I want every single row that I have selected from them. Obviously I can't do it when I have different select statements. How could I combine these two queries ?

```
SELECT GRADE_TYPE_CODE, ROUND(TO_CHAR(NUMERIC_GRADE),2) AS GRADE
FROM GRADE
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 10 AND SECTION_ID = 5
ORDER BY GRADE_TYPE_CODE DESC,NUMERIC_GRADE DESC;



SELECT 'Average is:' AS GRADE_TYPE_CODE,AVG(GRADE) AS GRADE
FROM
(
    SELECT AVG(NUMERIC_GRADE) AS GRADE
FROM GRADE
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 10 AND SECTION_ID = 5
GROUP BY GRADE_TYPE_CODE
) myInnerTable;
```

Comment: You have a grade_type_code with a value of 'Average is:' ????

Comment: Yes , I'd to display it just the way these two queries are. So I'd like to combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is here.  Why not just put "union all" between your two queries, and move the ORDER BY clause to the end?

```
SELECT GRADE_TYPE_CODE, ROUND(TO_CHAR(NUMERIC_GRADE),2) AS GRADE
FROM GRADE
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 10 AND SECTION_ID = 5

union all

SELECT 'Average is:' AS GRADE_TYPE_CODE,AVG(GRADE) AS GRADE
FROM
(
    SELECT AVG(NUMERIC_GRADE) AS GRADE
FROM GRADE
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 10 AND SECTION_ID = 5
GROUP BY GRADE_TYPE_CODE
) myInnerTable

order by 1 desc, 2 desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99a16/19/0

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could [create a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-oracle) and then union ALL from the two separate queries.