# oracle sql: split string and return unmatched part as other

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I have a table that looks like this:

```
AMT       TYPE
100       red, yellow, green, purple
200       red, green, blue, yellow
90        pink, blue, light red
......
```

What I want is to add up the amounts by color. For example, a final output should be:

```
AMT       TYPE
300       red
300       yellow
300       green
290       blue
190       other
```

Notice that 1. I don't want to include `light red` in `red`
and 2. I want to include all colors other than red, yellow, green, blue in to a new category "other".

My current code is

```
select sum(red), ... from (
      select
        case when trim(regexp_substr(type, red',1,1,'i')) is not null
             then amt
        else 0 end as red
        ......
      from mytable)
```

But it doesn't solve the problems I mentioned earlier. I also tried the following method, but it becomes so slow that it never ends. (Or maybe there is some error in this code?)

```
select color, sum(amt)
from (
     select trim(regexp_substr(type,'[^,]+', 1, level)) as color
     from mytable
     connect by level <= regexp_count(type, ',')+1)
group by color
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Now you know how unwieldy a schema becomes when it does not follow [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). I could consider creating a (temporary) pair of tables that describe the relationship between amounts and colors in a proper relational fashion, then write an obvious query.

Comment: Exactly... But I have no control over the database... Could you describe how can I create a temp table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-oracle

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I asking how to create that relation between amounts and colors...

Comment: You don't have to explicitly create a relation, since you don't have a well-formed color column in your table. Normally you would use a 'foreign key' constraint. See my answer below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a full list of colors?

Imagine that you do. Let there be a `table color(name varchar2(...) not null primary key)` that lists every color.

Then you could write something like:

```
select 
  color.name, sum(crazy_table.amt)
from
  color, crazy_table -- the latter is your original data
where
  crazy_table.type like '%, ' || color.name -- at the end of string
  or 
  crazy_table.type like color.name || ', %' -- at the start of string
  or  crazy_table.type like '%, ' || color.name || ', %' -- middle
  or
  crazy_table.type = color.name -- single entry, no commas
  or
  color.name = 'other' and not exists ( -- no known color matches
    select 1 from color as c2
    where instr(crazy_table.type, c2.name) > 0
  )
group by color.name
```

It would full-scan `crazy_table`, which is presumably large, doing index lookups on `color` table which is presumably much smaller, so performance should be ok.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't. But what I do have is a list of major colors and "other".

Comment: I've updated my answer assuming that SQL does _not_ short-circuit OR operators.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would get you the desired result. It

1.first splits the color values into separate rows, based on 737905's solution given to [convert comma separated string into rows](https://community.oracle.com/message/6863756) on OTN Discussion Forum.

2.uses the CASE statement to designate the 'other' category for colors besides red, yellow, green, and blue.

3.groups by color

4.orders by a pre-determined order of colors

```
WITH SPLIT_COLORS AS
  (
    SELECT
      AMT,
      TRIM(EXTRACT(column_value,'/e/text()')) COLOR
    FROM
      mytable x,
      TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<ROW><e>'
      ||REPLACE(type,',','</e><e>')
      ||'</e></ROW>'),'//e')))
  )
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN color NOT IN ('red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue') THEN 'other'
    ELSE color
  END AS color,
  SUM(amt) amt
FROM
  SPLIT_COLORS
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN color NOT IN ('red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue') THEN 'other'
    ELSE color
  END
ORDER BY
  CASE color
    WHEN 'red' THEN 1
    WHEN 'yellow' THEN 2
    WHEN 'green' THEN 3
    WHEN 'blue' THEN 4
    ELSE 5
  END;
```

You can test only the output of the first part (the CTE's - Common Table Expressions), as below:

```
WITH SPLIT_COLORS AS
  (
    SELECT
      AMT,
      TRIM(EXTRACT(column_value,'/e/text()')) COLOR
    FROM
      mytable x,
      TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<ROW><e>'
      ||REPLACE(type,',','</e><e>')
      ||'</e></ROW>'),'//e')))
  )
SELECT *
FROM SPLIT_COLORS;
```