# Create temporary table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ddl, temp-tables

I'm trying to create temporary table in PL/SQL developer and insert some data, but it throws error:

> ```
> ORA-00905
> ```

My code:

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Comment: Do you have Oracle 18c?

Comment: If you are asking about version it is 11.1

Comment: So your syntax is wrong see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-do-you-create-a-temporary-table-in-an-oracle-database

Answer (score 3):

[CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-do-you-create-a-temporary-table-in-an-oracle-database)  introduced only in Oracle 18:

> Oracle 18c added private temporary tables, which are single-session in-memory objects.

In previous version, you can create global temporary table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
id           NUMBER,
description  VARCHAR2(20)
);
```