# Group by running total resetting every time the counter is incremented

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table (my input would be just columns NIF, FILE and FILESIZE).

I would like to obtain columns PARTITION and SUBPARTITION with the following rules:

1. PARTITION should start with 1 and be incremented by 1 every tune SUBPARTITION reaches 8.
2. A single NIF cannot be in two different PARTITIONs. (This is the most restrictive condition actually).
3. SUBPARTITION must be incremented by 1 every time the running total in FILESIZE reaches 10. That running total must be reset when SUBPARTITION is incremented by 1.

Data:

```
  NIF  FILE FILESIZE    PARTITION   SUBPARTITION
  ----------------------------------------------
   A     C1        1            1              1
   A     C2        1            1              1
   A     C3        2            1              1
   A     C4        1            1              1
   B     C5        5            1              2
   B     C6        1            1              2
   C     C7        2            1              2
   C     C8        1            1              2
   D     C9        4            1              3
   D    C10        5            1              3
   D    C11        1            1              3
   D    C12        2            1              4
   D    C13        3            1              4
   D    C14        4            1              4
   D    C15        5            1              5
   E    C16        3            1              6
   E    C17        2            1              6
   E    C18        3            1              6
   E    C19        4            1              7
   F    C20        6            2              1
   F    C20        2            2              1
```

It does not need to be a single query, doing a PSLQL cursor would also be fine.

NOTE: this is the code to create the input table.

```
DROP TABLE my_table;
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  NIF VARCHAR2(10),
  FILE_ VARCHAR2(10),
  FILESIZE NUMBER
);

-- Insert the input data
INSERT INTO my_table (NIF, FILE_, FILESIZE)
    SELECT 'A', 'C1', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 'C2', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 'C3', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 'C4', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 'C5', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 'C6', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 'C7', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 'C8', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', 'C9', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', 'C10', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', 'C11', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', 'C12', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', 'C13', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', 'C14', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', 'C15', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'E', 'C16', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'E', 'C17', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'E', 'C18', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'E', 'C19', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'F', 'C20', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'F', 'C21', 2 FROM DUAL;
    
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Not sure it is possible generally. Consider 11 NIF='E' entries with  FILESIZE=9. Rule #3 requires  11 subpartitions must be created, rule #1 says you need at least 2 partitions for that, and rule #2 requires that all subs must be in a single partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use a combination of analytic functions and `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT cto,
       nif,
       file_,
       partition,
       mn - first_mn + 1 AS subpartition,
       total_size
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY cto
           ORDER BY SUBSTR(file_, 1, 1), TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(file_, 2))
         ) AS rn,
         SUM(filesize) OVER (PARTITION BY nif) AS nif_size
  FROM   my_table t
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY cto
  ORDER BY rn
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn,
    SUM(filesize) AS total_size
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( (same_nif* nif)* same_nif* end_nif )
  DEFINE
    same_nif AS nif = NEXT(nif),
    nif      AS  (NEXT(nif) IS NULL OR nif != NEXT(nif))
             AND SUM(filesize) + NEXT(nif_size) <= 10,
    end_nif  AS  SUM(filesize) <= 10
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY cto
  ORDER BY rn
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS partition,
    FIRST(mn) AS first_mn
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( (same_nif* nif)+ )
  DEFINE
    same_nif AS nif = NEXT(nif),
    nif      AS (NEXT(nif) IS NULL OR nif != NEXT(nif))
             AND mn - FIRST(mn) < 7
);
```

In first match, for the sub-partitions, the pattern:

- `same_nif* nif` will match from the current row to the end of the current `NIF` partition and ensure that the next `NIF` partition will also entirely be contained in the match by checking the current size plus the total size of the next `NIF` partition is within the limits;
- Wrapping it in `()*` allows that to be matched zero-or-more times (as many as is possible);
- The final `same_nif* end_nif` allows the match to partially match a set of rows with the same `nif` values (such as the files C9, C10 and C11 which has the same `nif` as C12, C13 and C14) but would be in a different group as they file size totals more than the limit. Without a different end condition you could end up either grouping C1 through C5 or not being able to split the `D` `nif` values.

In the second match, for the partitions, the `nif` values need to be kept together in the same match (whereas for sub-partitions `nif` values can span multiple matches) and, apart from that, the only check needed is that there are not more than 7 sub-partitions in a group.

Which, for the sample data (which has an added `CTO` column and an additional `nif` group `G` that is too large to be combined in the same partition as the previous `nif` group `F`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  CTO NUMBER,
  NIF VARCHAR2(10),
  FILE_ VARCHAR2(10),
  FILESIZE NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO my_table (CTO, NIF, FILE_, FILESIZE)
    SELECT 1, 'A', 'C1', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A', 'C2', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A', 'C3', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'A', 'C4', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'B', 'C5', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'B', 'C6', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'C', 'C7', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'C', 'C8', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D', 'C9', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D', 'C10', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D', 'C11', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D', 'C12', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D', 'C13', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D', 'C14', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'D', 'C15', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'E', 'C16', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'E', 'C17', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'E', 'C18', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'E', 'C19', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'F', 'C20', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'F', 'C21', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'G', 'C' || (LEVEL + 21), 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;
```

Outputs:

| CTO | NIF | FILE_ | PARTITION | SUBPARTITION | TOTAL_SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | C1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | A | C2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | A | C3 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | A | C4 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | B | C5 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | B | C6 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | C | C7 | 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | C | C8 | 1 | 2 | 9 |
| 1 | D | C9 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | D | C10 | 1 | 3 | 9 |
| 1 | D | C11 | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | D | C12 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | D | C13 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | D | C14 | 1 | 4 | 9 |
| 1 | D | C15 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | E | C16 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 1 | E | C17 | 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | E | C18 | 1 | 6 | 8 |
| 1 | E | C19 | 1 | 7 | 4 |
| 1 | F | C20 | 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 1 | F | C21 | 2 | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | G | C22 | 3 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | G | C23 | 3 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | G | C24 | 3 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | G | C25 | 3 | 4 | 10 |
| 1 | G | C26 | 3 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | G | C27 | 3 | 6 | 10 |
| 1 | G | C28 | 3 | 7 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NicfmZMO)

Comment: Sorry because this was not in the original scope of the question but a slight enhancement. If there was another column at the beginning called CTO and I wanted to make the same logic but starting over again when CTO changes, how would I modify the pattern? Also, why have you defined the pattern as ( (same_nif* nif)* same_nif* end_nif ) as opposed to same_nif * nif * end_nif?

Comment: @JaviTorre Updated to implement partitioning by `CTO` and also to fully implement rule #2 (although you may still have issues if you have more than 7 sub-partitions with the same `nif` as it is then impossible to meet rule #2).

Comment: Pure genius! Thanks so much!

Comment: What does the pattern mean though? And why not same_nif * nif * end_nif?

Comment: @JaviTorre The first pattern is for the sub-partitions and needs to be able to split `nif` groups on the `filesize` limit so that successive sub-partitions can have the same `nif` value. The second pattern is for splitting into partitions and the `nif` values need to be kept together. The patterns are different because they have different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-do-you-create-a-temporary-table-in-an-oracle-database) or a real yable with the fields of (NIF, FILE, FILESIZE, PARTITION, SUBPARTITION). You could add an id to it as well, but for the purpose of this answer I will describe only the absolute minimum.

You would set PARTITION and SUBPARTITION to be nullable and insert lines via commands like

```
insert into yourtable(NIF, FILE, FILESIZE)
values('A', 'C1', 1);
```

and implement a [before insert trigger](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php) that will find `max(PARTITION)` to find out what the current partition is as well as the `max(SUBPARTITION)` of that partition along with the `sum(FILESIZE)` in that partition. Something like (this is an agnostic query, you will need to save the fields `into` local variables)

```
select PARTITION, SUBPARTITION, sum(FILESIZE) storage_use
from yourtable
group by PARTITION, SUBPARTITION
order by PARTITION desc, SUBPARTITION desc
limit 1
```

From here on, inside your trigger you can see whether `storage_use` + the actual `FILESIZE` of the record you are to insert is greater than 10. If not, then you set `PARTITION` and `SUBPARTITION` of your new record to those that you found in the query. If not, then you can increment `SUBPARTITION` as long as it's lower than or equal with 8. If `SUBPARTITION` is 8 and `storage_use` does not allow you to fit the new record into it, then store `PARTITION + 1` and `SUBPARTITION + 1` as `PARTITION` and `SUBPARTITION`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MODEL clause:

```
select nif, file_, filesize, partition, subpartition 
from (
    select 
      row_number() over(order by nif, to_number(substr(file_,2))) as rn, 
      nif, file_, to_number(substr(file_,2)) as file_order,
      filesize 
    from my_table
)
model
    dimension by (rn)
    measures( nif as nif, file_ as file_, file_order as file_order, 
        filesize as filesize,
        0 as partition, 0 as incsubpartition, 1 as subpartition, 0 as running_total )
    rules (
        running_total[any] = 
           case when nvl(running_total[cv()-1],0) + filesize[cv()] >= 10 
           then filesize[cv()]
           else nvl(running_total[cv()-1],0) + filesize[cv()]
           end,
        incsubpartition[any] = 
           case when nvl(running_total[cv()-1],0) + filesize[cv()] >= 10 
           then 1
           else 0
           end,
       -- rule 3
       subpartition[any] = nvl(subpartition[cv()-1],1) + incsubpartition[cv()], 
       partition[any] = 
           case when subpartition[cv()] = 8 and subpartition[cv()-1] <> 8 
           then partition[cv()-1] + 1
           else nvl(partition[cv()-1],1)
           end,
       -- rule 1
       subpartition[any] = 
          case when subpartition[cv()] = 8 
          then 1 
          else subpartition[cv()]
          end,
       -- rule 2
       partition[any] =
          case when nif[cv()] = nif[cv()-1] 
          then partition[cv()-1]
          else partition[cv()]
          end
   )
order by nif, file_order
;


NIF FILE_   FILESIZE    PARTITION   SUBPARTITION
A   C1  1   1   1
A   C2  1   1   1
A   C3  2   1   1
A   C4  1   1   1
B   C5  5   1   2
B   C6  1   1   2
C   C7  2   1   2
C   C8  1   1   2
D   C9  4   1   3
D   C10 5   1   3
D   C11 1   1   4
D   C12 2   1   4
D   C13 3   1   4
D   C14 4   1   5
D   C15 5   1   5
E   C16 3   1   6
E   C17 2   1   6
E   C18 3   1   6
E   C19 4   1   7
F   C20 6   2   1
F   C21 2   2   1
```